# Flask keeps loading old version of HTML template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I changed my `index.html` template so that it would extend `base.html`. And also changed the content of `index.html` a little. But Flask keeps loading unchanged version of `index.html`

I've tried following:

- Deleted `index.html` temporarily. Flask started to complain `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html`
- The same happens if I change the name of file to be used here `return render_template('index.html')`
- To make sure that **Atom** editor really applies changes to the file on my server, I opened the file with **nano** over **ssh**. Changes are really there.
- Cleared browser cache. Tried different browsers. Old version of html template is loaded.

I have no more ideas. 
Do you have any idea what else should be checked?

Comment: You're probably looking at the wrong file.

Comment: But if I delete or rename it over ssh, Flask doesn't find it. And when I open it I see the changes in it. And when I rename it back, Flask still loads unchanged version to the browser. This is driving me crazy slowly )

Answer (score 1):

This is very strange but it was solved by ***RESAVING*** `base.html`.

Though `base.html` was on server, when I did some changes to it and resaved, Flask started to load ***the new version*** of `index.html`.

I have no idea how this worked.